# Is it good design to use channels for concurrent database calls?

Tags: database, web, go

I am working on a web application (written in go) with a statistics page. This page contains several graphs that is backed up with data from the database. There are several calls to the database made sequentially as it stands now.

Is this a good place to use channels in order to get parallel calls to the database and possibly boost performance? Regardless of the performance boost - is it considered good design to use channels for a case like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Channels don't by themselves boost performance. In fact channel operations are quite a bit more expensive than function calls.

What you should be asking yourself is "Should I be making concurrent calls to the database?".

If the answer to that is "yes", then your next step should be deciding
how to structure your database client code to enable that.
Goroutines will certainly feature, and channels
are highly likely to be useful too, in order to send the resulting
data to where it is needed.

Comment: In addition to these considerations, there is also the database itself. Running K queries in parallel is not faster than K queries in serial depending on what kind of workload it imposes. The only way to know this would be to measure.

Comment: conclusion: will keep it serial until/if it becomes a problem (damn: wanted to try channels)